Does "proceeding the absorption" mean the same as "taking place after the absorption"?
This is a part of an article "Differences between fluorescence, phosphorescence, incandescence" from www.quirkyscience.com
"Fluorescence is the rapid, even immediate emission of radiation, visible or invisible, proceeding the absorption of higher frequency (higher energy, shorter wavelength) radiation such as ultraviolet light."
I know that "proceed" means:
do something after something else.
"opposite the front door was a staircase which I proceeded to climb" (Oxford Languages)
Is this the meaning here? Does it mean that the emission of radiation happens after the absorption? Shouldn't the wording be "proceeding after the absorption"?

This is presumably a typo for "preceding".

I’m voting to close this question because it's about a typo (proceeding for preceding).

it is the opposite of preceding ... it would be clearer to use the word follows instead ... the ultraviolet light is absorbed, and then fluorescent light is emitted

It is NOT a typo for preceding, as is clear from the logic of what is being said. Fluorescence obviously cannot happen BEFORE something has absorbed the radiation energy that triggers it. 'Proceeding from' is more normal, but 'proceeding' can be used this way.

@fred2: No, 'proceeding' can't be used adjectivally (attributively or predicatively). I don;t really care enough about it to dig in to the exact semantics, since it's not valid English in the first place.

@fred2 Agreed, it can't be "preceding"; I joined the vote for a typo too soon. I would still vote to close as an omitted word instead; "proceed" has no transitive usage.

Note, while quirkyscience.com appears to do a reasonable job of presenting its topics in approachable language, it hasn't had the benefit of the traditional publishing process, including proofreading and editing. I see a couple of style typos just in the few sentences on the table-of-contents page.

@fred2 but in the case of "proceeding from" as you suggested, the sentence would mean that fluorescence is 'caused' by the absorption of light and not that it 'happens after' it, right? I base that on this Oxford dictionary definition: proceed from
​(formal) to be caused by or be the result of something
In some cases appeals may proceed directly from the High Court to the House of Lords.

@StaticBounce ... see comments on my full answer, and the corrected version of the answer I've provided there now (post comments). But yes, I think the author means 'arising from', or 'caused by'.

The nearest plausible sense of proceed here is the full OED definition 7.b 1578–1714 In extended use: to advance to some status or function; to grow or develop into, to become (what is expressed by the complement). Obsolete.

I would vote to leave this question open, as it raises the next question (possibly on ELU)  "Why is 'proceeding'  wrong when 'preceding 'is a fairly common word?" I'm not arguing that it is a word. Several comments have already said "It isn't in the dictionary" and I accept that, I can't remember ever having seen it used.

@Peter Jennings Proceeding is a continuous form of the verb proceed. It's a different word with a different meaning than precede. This word is in all of the dictionaries as well as the word precede. I've had a problem with the usage of the word proceed, namely that it's not followed by "for" or "from". I didn't think someone would doubt the existence of any of these words as I know them well as a non-native speaker :P

It is not a typo for preceding, it is typo for proceeding from.  Junior school physics.

Your interpretation is correct. This use of 'proceeding' must be in error, and is not one for which any other modern example exists. The author appears to be describing the process causing fluorescence (radiation happens first, immediately triggering florescence as a result. Therefore the flourescence 'proceeds' (in the author's terms) rather than 'precedes' the radiation).
This might normally be expressed as "... arising from the absorption of higher frequency (higher energy, shorter wavelength) radiation ..."
The author appears to be erroneously using 'proceeds' as a literal opposite of 'precedes'. While this logically might appear to make sense, it is not grammatical and, as can be seen from other comments on this question, is confusing and ambiguous.
(For the sake of pedantry, I checked the 1933 edition of OED, just to see if there was a record of 'proceeding' being used this way, but, although there are a couple of very old usages that are somewhat along the same lines, there was nothing identical.)

It's not "unusual". It;s plain wrong.

It's often wise to soften absolute statements, but you give too much credit here. It's not "unusual" or "not customary"; it's a true mistake, even if we're able to guess the meaning from context.

@FumbleFingers I have reworded to clarify that the usage must be in error.
